# I'm not able to get the selected value from ContentControl and I'm not able also to set the value I want

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a dependent drop-down list where the user may select the first drop-down list and all the other dependent drop-down list will change automatically.

```
Select Case ContentControl.Title
  Case "T1_1"
   Select Case ContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Item.Value
     Case "male"

      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_2").Item(1).Value = "male"
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_3").Item(1).Value = "male"
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_4").Item(1).Value = "male"

     Case "female"

      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_2").Item(1).Value = "female"
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_3").Item(1).Value = "female"
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("T1_4").Item(1).Value = "female"

  End Select
```

I'm not able to get the selected value "male or female" and I'm not able also to set the value I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I looked up some time ago, Microsoft just forgot to let you query the selected `value` of a DropDown-ContentControl.
You can only get `ContentControl.Range.Text`, so if you need to look up the corresponding shorthand-value, you have to loop through:

```
Public Function getCCDD_value(cc As ContentControl) As String
     getCCDD_value = ""
     For Each Item In cc.DropdownListEntries
         If Item.Text = cc.Range.Text Then
             getCCDD_value = Item.Value
         End If
     Next
End Function
```

For changing, you can simply set the ContentControl's  `.Range.Text`. It must match an existing dropdown-listentries-text (case sensitive) in order to return the correct `value` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem like "extra work", if you are in a position to map your content control to a Custom XML Part, you can get the value directly from the mapping.

As an example (you would have to work somewhat harder to do this correctly), starting with a new document:

```
Sub insertTestDDLCCandCXP()
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
Dim l As Long
Dim sCXP As String
For l = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count To 4 Step -1
 ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(l).Delete
Next l

sCXP = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><ccData xmlns='bibadia1'><ccDDL1Value/></ccData>"
With ActiveDocument
  ' add a part
  .CustomXMLParts.Add sCXP
  ' clear out the document
  .Range.Delete
  Set cc = .ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
  With cc
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "dt1", "val1"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "dt2", "val2"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "dt3", "val3"
    ' using "ns0" is a kludge - you should determine the namespace that
    ' Word wants to use
    .XMLMapping.SetMapping ("//ns0:ccData/ns0:ccDDL1Value")
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

You can then retrieve the Value using (again for example)

```
activedocument.ContentControls(1).XMLMapping.CustomXMLNode.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1 seems to be the right one. Here's the VSTO C# version that gives you the .Value. You can get the ordinal position with .Index. Returns null for no or mismatched selection.

```
        var currentChoice = cc.DropdownListEntries.Cast<ContentControlListEntry>()
                              .FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Text == cc.Range.Text)
                              ?.Value;
```